# How to Java Midi STOP

Tags: java, audio, midi

How to stop any sound from java application?

Comment: I've removed the "midi" tag from this question because I don't think it's directly related to that.  Sending a midi all-notes-off message is not the same as killing all sound right away -- and you should be more specific about what you are asking. ;)

Comment: I don't understand well your question. Did you mean "control the system volume from a Java application?" or "playing/stop playing a sound from a Java application"

Comment: this question needs serious clarification. It sort of sounds like a user has a java app that's making noise he wants to mute individually from his other running applications. It doesn't /sound/ like a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Sound API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/).

To simply mute sound you can do something like this:

```
Port p = (Port)AudioSystem.getLine(Port.Info.SPEAKER);
p.open();

//print out volume
FloatControl vol = (FloatControl)p.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
System.out.println("Current Volume: " + vol.getValue());

//mute sound
BooleanControl mute = (BooleanControl)p.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
mute.setValue(true);

p.close();
```

Comment: I think he did mean, not just muting, but solution for pause functionality, to resume playback after. What do you think?